# how to pass input to python script running in another python script?

Tags: python

In one python file, I have this:

```
# Some code here 
exec("i=input()\nprint(i)")
# Insert some way to pass input to code above
```

When I run this, the whole script pauses and waits for a user to type an input into the console. Is there a way I can automate passing the input without human interaction. In other words, I'm trying to pass an input to a python script that is embedded in another python script without human interaction. Is this possible?

Comment: Use asynchrony.

Answer (score 0):

Before using any methods inside the `exec()` function one must keep in mind about what all functions do `exec()` support. To view this we may use `dir()` function.

```
from math import *
exec("print(dir())")
```

Output:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__',
 '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 
'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 
'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 
'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial',
 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 
'hypot', 'inf', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf',
'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 
'log2', 'modf', 'nan', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin',
 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

As you can see `exec()` function doesn't support `input()`. This makes sense because `input()` method is specifically designed to take input from user.